# How can I delete this file with odd permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, acl

I accidentally created a file without delete permission.

"Everyone" has the following permissions: [image: Dialog showing read and delete permissions selected] and "OWNER RIGHTS" has no permissions at all.

In string form, the security descriptor is `D:(A;;0x120001;;;WD)(A;;;;;OW)`

Windows Explorer will not allow me to delete or rename the file, even as administrator. The `cacls` command is not able to change the permissions, even as administrator.

Note that it is not possible for the file owner (me) to change the permissions because having "OWNER RIGHTS" in the ACL disables this.

How can I delete this file?

Comment: Try Unlocker V1.9.2 available from Majorgeeks.   I have this and use it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have ownership, because I created the file

Comment: Are you sure to be the owner of the file ? Related to microsoft documentation : `Owners can always change permissions to objects, even when they're denied all access to the object`. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/take-ownership-of-files-or-other-objects

Comment: @S.Brottes believe it or not, Microsoft lied. If your ACL has an entry for "OWNER RIGHTS" then the owner does not automatically have permission to change permissions.

Comment: Do you have admin permission on the system ? It seems to work when trying to delete with elevated command prompt.

Comment: @S.Brottes I cannot delete the file with an elevated command prompt, though it says the file is not found - I guess the `del` command doesn't know what to print for access denied errors.